# How to hide and show elements on mouseover of containing element using Javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a containing div, with a 'h1' title an 'p' description within it. I want the 'description paragraph' hidden while the 'title' is visible on page load, and when the mouse enters the 'container', the title fades to hidden and description fades to visible, and then to swap visibility back to its original visibility on mouseout. I was not able to achieve what i wanted with CSS alone.

I have low knowlege of the workings of javascript, but I can somewhat make of it when looking at it, any help would be greatly appreciated. Also I can provide more info if needed.

```
<div class="container">
    <h1 class="name">Title</h1>
    <p>description</p>
</div>
```

Comment: This question shows 0 research effort.

Comment: Did you ignore all suggestions that must have been given when you wrote this? There must be hundreds

Comment: No i did not simply ignore the many suggestions i found when I DID the research for what i was looking for, however much of the content and answers i came across were not exactly answering what i needed/the way i needed. But thanks for the input.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use CSS transition to fade effect.

First set the `opacity` of all paragraphs to zero. When hover over heading, increase the opacity of paragraph and decrease the opacity of heading gradually.

```css
.container p {
  opacity: 0;
  -webkit-transition: opacity 1s ease-in;
  -moz-transition: opacity 1s ease-in;
  -ms-transition: opacity 1s ease-in;
  -o-transition: opacity 1s ease-in;
  transition: opacity 1s ease-in;
}
.container h1 {
  -webkit-transition: opacity 1s ease-in;
  -moz-transition: opacity 1s ease-in;
  -ms-transition: opacity 1s ease-in;
  -o-transition: opacity 1s ease-in;
  transition: opacity 1s ease-in;
}
.container:hover p {
  opacity: 1;
}
.container:hover h1 {
  opacity: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <h1 class="name">Title</h1>
  <p>description</p>
</div>
<div class="container">
  <h1 class="name">Title</h1>
  <p>description</p>
</div>
<div class="container">
  <h1 class="name">Title</h1>
  <p>description</p>
</div>
<div class="container">
  <h1 class="name">Title</h1>
  <p>description</p>
</div>
```

You can also use jQuery's `hover` and `animate` method

```js
$('.container').hover(function() {
  $(this).find('p').animate({
    opacity: 1
  }).end().find('h1').animate({
    opacity: 0
  });
}, function() {
  $(this).find('p').animate({
    opacity: 0
  }).end().find('h1').animate({
    opacity: 1
  });
});
```

```css
.container p {
  opacity: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <h1 class="name">Title</h1>
  <p>description</p>
</div>
<div class="container">
  <h1 class="name">Title</h1>
  <p>description</p>
</div>
<div class="container">
  <h1 class="name">Title</h1>
  <p>description</p>
</div>
<div class="container">
  <h1 class="name">Title</h1>
  <p>description</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you for the help, this works smoothly without the need for scripts.

Answer (score 0):

Use .hide() and .show() functions. 
Initially make description as display : none in css ,also use the mouseout() and mouseover() function

```
<div class="container">
    <h1 class="name">Title</h1>
    <p id="desc">description</p>
</div>

$('.container').mouseout(function(){
     $('.name').show();
     $('#desc').hide();
});

$('.container').mouseover(function(){
    $('.name').hide();
    $('#desc').show();
});

#desc{
    display:none;
}
```

JSfiddle : 
http://jsfiddle.net/n470z649/

Comment: This script method does work well, I chose the other answer only because it uses CSS alone, but thank you for your contribution!